# CentOS“-bash: a2enmod: command not found”

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

when I configured pnp4nagios,the following questions happened.

> PHP GD extension→ PHP GD extension not available
>
> PHP zlib extension→   PHP zlib extension not available
>
> PHP socket extension→ PHP socket extension not available
>
> Apache Rewrite Module→    Apache mod_rewrite is not enabled

google told me perhaps my php was broken during the installation.
Also,I got this page[enabling-mod-rewrite-on-ubuntu](http://www.jarrodoberto.com/articles/2011/11/enabling-mod-rewrite-on-ubuntu)

But,my server is CentOS,I carried out the command "a2enmod rewrite",the result is "-bash: a2enmod: command not found"……

What can I do?Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

a2enmod is a debianism, on CentOS you will need to do this manually. Please refer to the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to find out how to do this.

Comment: "debianism" is a word I appreciate, coming from Ubuntu.

Comment: @Dennis So many words for RTFM. Even the link points to the docs front page :D

Comment: This "manuallity" doesn't get life easier, when you're automating setup

Comment: CentOS team is so arrogant :(

Comment: https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7/

Comment: apache management in ubuntu is so much nicer, would love to see the centos guys do the same

Answer (score 7):

PHP zlib and sockets are part of php-common. Install php-gd and php-common

```
yum install php php-gd php-common
```

to enable sockets find the PHP configuration directory and run the following commands in the terminal

```
./configure --enable-sockets
make && make install
```

Apache rewrite module allows URL rewriting. It's enabled by Default in Centos 7. Check if it's already enabled in your version. The following command outputs a list of Apache modules that are currently enabled:

```
httpd -M
```

If it is not already enabled, you will need to enable it by modifying the configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf
```

and include the following line

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Save the file and restart the Apache server

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: On my server (CentOS 6.9, Apache 2.2.15), there isn't a conf.modules.d folder. Instead, I need to modify the main Apache configuration file: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Most of the needed mods are already installed. You can check for installed mods via:
`httpd -M | grep modname`

if these aren't loaded, they might need to be activated in a conf file alike: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

if you have mods which need to be added, usually these will be installed via:
`dnf install  modname`